# IE6 security login (debugging via VirtualPC)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis

I am debugging my ASP.NET application on my Windows XP box with a virtual directory set up in IIS (5.1).

I am also running **VirtualPC** with XP and IE6 for testing purposes. When I connect to my real machine from the virtual machine, I enter the URL: http://machinename/projectname.

I get a security popup to connect to my machine (which I expect), but the User name field is disabled. I cannot change it from machinename\Guest to machinename\username in order to connect.

How do I get this to enable so I can enter the correct credentials.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to allow anonymous users. Can you connect from other machines on your network?

Try changing your virtual directory's authentication settings, so that anonymous users are allowed (**MyVirtualDir > Properties > Authentication**).

Answer (score 2):

uncheck allow anonymous on the virtual dir and check integrated authentication. also make sure you are not logging into the virtual xp box as guest or a user w/o a password.